# Связка Java и Python

Tags: java, python

Часто натыкаюсь на вакансии в которых сказано, что требуется backend-программист с опытом программирования на Java и Python вместе.

Как это понимать? Как связаны эти языки ?

Я вот никаких связей между сервлетами и python-серверами не вижу...

Comment: может быть работодатель хочет переписать существующее приложение с питона на яву (или наоборот)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Data Scientist](https://adtmag.com/articles/2016/01/08/data-science-skills.aspx) - один из многих примеров

цитата:

> "**Hadoop, Python, Java, and R** round out our top five in-demand skills,"
>   Tenuto said. "It's worth noting that we didn't ask about Excel skills
>   and that's still something you see in myriad job listings. Old habits
>   die hard."

другая цитата:

> The CrowdFlower report mostly jives with a similar study conducted
>   last summer by Packt Publishing Ltd. to **determine the top money-making**
>   **skills in the data science and business intelligence (BI) industries**.
>   That report listed the top five as **Python, SQL, R, Java and
>   JavaScript**.

Comment: JS, Python, Java и SQL - понятно. Но при чем тут R ? Разве он не для мат расчетов ?

Comment: @faoxis, он как раз для Data Science - для обработки больших объемов данных